# Android uses-feature usage

Tags: android, android-permissions

What is the difference between the following:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
```

and

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
```

Is the later even a valid declaration? 
Is uses-feature only valid when associated with hardware components or even valid for system features?

Also, for every permission group is there a list of corresponding hardware components it uses, so that marking optional features would be easier ?

Comment: did ask for the difference between hardware permission and system permission?

Comment: Is uses-feature only valid when associated with hardware components or even valid for system features?

Comment: valid for standalone system features as well.

Comment: When I mention <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />, do I also need to mention <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" /> ?

Comment: These permissions are standalone...
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
So, to answer your question, no, you don't need to

Comment: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required="false" />`  not `<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />`

Comment: @RoShanShan - Do you mean the latter is invalid ?

Comment: @jay Right the second is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />
```

> Declares a single hardware or software feature that is used by the
>   application.

For more information read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)